# AWS Workspaces issue when trying to pay with a credit card

Tags: amazon-web-services, region, amazon-workspaces

We got some users using Windows 10 on AWS workspaces for regular basis, some of they use the web browser to pay online the company's services (taxes, energy, etc).

As we're allocated on Guatemala City and the company's credit cards are registered in Guatemala, several websites are showing us error messages like "It is not possible to pay because you're allocated on USA" and in other cases the websites are showing USD rates making everything more expensive than usual.

We know this is happening because AWS datacenters are allocated on USA and we're also clear that Windows 10 now has activated a feature for location tracking, we're awareness about that, but the question is, do you have any idea on how to sort this? how can we still paying from the Workspaces like we were allocated on Guatemala.

This issue started when we upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10, just for you know that the issue is associated with the OS version.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web browser can't see the settings of the host computer, aside from the user's locale setting.

It's probably related to the IP address being used by the WorkSpace, which is then translated to a geographical location using services like [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/).

Unfortunately, Amazon WorkSpaces is only available in N.Virginia and Oregon in your part of the world.

If the web sites are doing geo-restriction by IP address, there's not much you can do.